# Are these chinese letterings real or fake

Tags: learning

What does these words mean? Im finding out if someone is faking it. Saying hes a chinese but actually not. Im looking at his profile and got the name and status. Are these words make any sense or not? If yes, the meaning?
[His status](https://postimg.org/image/bwg4yeypb/)

[His name](https://postimg.org/image/q6tvrla83/)

Answer (score 1):

Those are real Chinese characters.

- The three characters in the status means "(I) won't chitchat" or "no time for 
  chitchat"
- The four characters in the name means "day dreaming" or, literally "white day make dream"

Comment: Is it too standard? Like from google translate? Any1 can do that. And  What about the name?

Comment: I updated my answer above.  I can't ascertain how he got those characters (by himself or by google translate).

Answer (score 1):

It is just common internet pseudonym/pen-name/call-sign

> 白日做梦 : daydreams
>
> 不闲聊 : no small talk.

Just like anyone using a cool/fancy call-sign when register themselves in a forum, groups chat,etc.